# Why are asp-route and asp-action mutually exclusive?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-routing

I have the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
routes.MapRoute(name: "out", template: "outbound/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Why is this not allowed? This outgoing URL is generated from `HomeController` and action method = `Index`

```
<a asp-route="out" asp-action="a" asp-route-id="someIdValue">This is an outoing URL.</a>
```

The view that generates this outgoing URL is from the `HomeController`'s `Index` method.

Why wouldn't it use the `"out"` route template and just use `"a"` for the action, and using `Home` as the controller to generate `/outbound/Home/a/someIdValue`?

I'm able to provide a value for `id`, why can't I provide a value for the action?

Comment: Could you add the link that is actually generated? Or do you get an error?

Comment: @janw yes, /outbound/Home/A works because I have a HomeController and an action method called a()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `asp-area` rather than `asp-route`.

[image]

Startup.cs

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "out", template: "{area=Outbound}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Controller

```
[Area("Outbound")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}



    <a href="/outbound/home/index">Go to Outoing’ Home Page by href="/outbound/home/index"</a> <br>

    <a asp-area="Outbound" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Go to Outoing’ Home Page by asp-area</a><br>

    @Html.ActionLink("Go to Outoing’ Home Page by @Html.ActionLink", "Index", "Home", new { area = "Outbound" })
```

> Screenshots of test

[image]

**[asp-route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1#asp-route)**

The `asp-route` attribute is used for creating a URL linking directly to a named route. Using routing attributes, a route can be named as shown in the `SpeakerController` and used in its `Evaluations` action:

```
[Route("/Speaker/Evaluations", 
       Name = "speakerevals")]
public IActionResult Evaluations() => View();
```

In the following markup, the `asp-route` attribute references the named route:

```
<a asp-route="speakerevals">Speaker Evaluations</a>
```

The Anchor Tag Helper generates a route directly to that controller action using the URL `/Speaker/Evaluations`. The generated HTML:

```
<a href="/Speaker/Evaluations">Speaker Evaluations</a>
```

If `asp-controller` or `asp-action` is specified in addition to `asp-route`, the route generated may not be what you expect.

**To avoid a route conflict, `asp-route` shouldn't be used with the `asp-controller` and `asp-action` attributes**.

---

BTW, `default route` and `area route` automatically assign an order value to their endpoints based on the order they are invoked.

---

> **Difference between `asp-route` and `asp-controller` & `asp-action`**

Route names(`asp-route`) can be used to generate a URL based on a specific route.

In the same time, `{controller}/{action}` also generate URL maps to `Home` controller and `Test` action.

```
    //works
    <a asp-controller="home" asp-action="test">asp-controller="home" asp-action="test"</a><br>

    //works
    <a asp-route="test">asp-route="test"</a><br>

    //InvalidOperationException
    <a asp-route="test" asp-controller="home" asp-action="test">asp-route="test" asp-controller="home" asp-action="test"</a>
```

`InvalidOperationException` occurs when set both in one `<a>` tag.

[image]

Comment: This is interesting, and I didn't know that using `asp-area` achieves a similar functionality. But this answer still doesn't explain _why_ `asp-route` and `asp-action` are mutually exclusive, although this question is probably better suited as a GitHub issue, anyway. Also, it looks like the `asp-route` paragraph of your answer is a direct quote from the documentation; it may be preferable to make this more clear [by using a block quote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Hi, @janw, tks for your suggestion. I will check and learn it.

Comment: "If asp-controller or asp-action is specified in addition to asp-route, the route generated may not be what you expect.". Why would that be the case? Can you provide an example? In my question, if it allowed you to specify both asp-route and asp-action, I would expect it to generate /outbound/Home/a, which I assume it would if it were able to compile.

Comment: Hi,@David Klempfner, it won't run success if you specify both `asp-route` and `asp-action`.  I explained and tested in the end of answer.

Comment: @Lightman I understand that, but my question is, why is that the case? Why is not allowed?

Comment: @David Klempfner That's just how they designed. `asp-route` is used for creating a URL linking directly to a named route. If `asp-controller` or `asp-action` is specified in addition to `asp-route`, there will be two routes and causes a route conflict.

Comment: @Lightman I appreciate you answering the "how", but what I'm looking for is the "why". I don't see any reason why they had to design it this way.

Comment: Me neither. No clue about the why.